# Connecting two 50-ohm transmission lines

Tags: impedance-matching

I've made sure my two board input/output side has been set 50-ohm terminated as in this picture:

[image]

Now I connect the two boards with two 50 ohm coaxial cables with SMA-male to BNC-female connectors in the middle:

```
-----------                                                          -----------  
| Board-A |------50-ohm-cable-A---<sma-to-BNC>---50-ohm-cable-B------| Board-B |
-----------                                                          -----------
```

Is this cable still 50-ohms like the index of refraction is still continuous, or is it 100-ohms because I connected them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable is still 50 Ω, you haven't changed the cable.

The cable is still terminated in 50 Ω both ends. That is, assuming Vsource is a very low impedance (ideally a zero impedance voltage source), and that any additional components loading the connection on the B board are very high impedance (ideally open) compared with 50 Ω.

V source itself is driving a load of 100 Ω, as Rs is in series with the 50 Ω impedance of the line. That's one of the advantages of a source termination resistor. The amplifier driving it doesn't have such a low impedance to drive, although it may need 2x gain if you want the same voltage on the transmission line as its input.

Comment: Many thanks!! I always looked 50 ohm terminated resistor which select 49.x ohm(1%). Is reason because of you mentioned "Vsource has little impendence (not assigned 50 ohm Ro)"?

Comment: And our case is video buffer, so gain may be about +1V/V. I refer to [LMH6722](https://www.ti.com/product/LMH6722) to design our buffer. Yes! as you mentioned! TI always recommend +2 V/V in its example design. Moreover, some product focus on this application, such as [OPA3693](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa3693), it default +2V/V internal, so we don't add additional resistor to set gain. Today, I understand why those product always default +2 V/V even integrated resistor into ICs. Many thanks!